# Java Multithreading - Banking Application

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a scenario where in I have to perform money transfer from account  A to B.
For that purpose I used synchronized block something like:

```
public void transaction(Account A , Account B , Number Amount){
    Synchronized(this){
        A - amount;
        B + amount;
        commit;
    }
}
```

This approach is fine for transaction between A to B, but the problem is : it blocks all other transactions as well.
i.e. While transaction A--> B is going on , at the same time transaction between C-->D will also be blocked . 
Ideally transaction Between A->B should not affect transaction C->D.

How can this scenario be handled in Java?
Thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: Why would you post such poorly formatted code? Please don't make it harder to understand your code. Edited and fixed.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html - this is where you should start.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels don't simply use Account as the monitor, that can cause a deadlock. When A transfers money to B and B transfers money to A at the same time: Thread 1 locks A, Thread 2 locks B, Thread 1 tries to lock B but Thread 2 already locks on it, Thread 2 tries to lock A but Thread 1 already locks on it -> deadlock. You can do it if you always lock the Account with the lower ID first

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels .. Thanks for indenting it nicely.  However I did not understand how syncronising Account will solve the problem ? Could be please eloborate a litle bit.

Comment: @rollback: you're right

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment yesterday, you can solve your problem using the Accounts as your monitor.
To prevent a deadlock, you always have to lock the Objects in the same order:

```
public void transcation(Account a, Account b, long amount) {
    long id1 = a.getID();// The ID must be final and unique!
    long id2 = b.getID();
    Object monitor1 = id1 < id2 ? a : b;
    Object monitor2 = id1 > id2 ? a : b;

    synchronized (monitor1) {
        synchronized (monitor2) {
            a.setCredit(a.getCredit() + amount);
            b.setCredit(b.getCredit() - amount);
        }
    }
}
```